# Angular Router Link Active

Tags: angular

I have a router which takes an id param. When navigating to the route for the first time, router link active works fine and it applies the class, but when navigating with different id for example, router link active doesn't work correctly. Has anyone experienced it before ?

my html file:

```
<div class="sidenav-content-wrapper" fxLayout="column" fxFill
  [ngClass]="{ 'sidenav-content-wrapper--closed': !menuState.isOpened }">
  <div class="sidenav-button" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayoutAlign="start center" routerLink="/companies"
    [queryParams]="{feature: 'companies'}" [ngClass]="{
      'sidenav-button-active': selectedFeature === 'companies'
    }">
    <mat-icon class="sidenav-button-icon">business</mat-icon>
    <span class="sidenav-button-text">Companies</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sidenav-button" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayoutAlign="start center" [queryParams]="{feature: 'branches'}"
    [routerLink]="['/branches', selectedCompany]" [ngClass]="{
      'sidenav-button-active': selectedFeature === 'branches'
    }">
    <mat-icon class="sidenav-button-icon">work</mat-icon>
    <span class="sidenav-button-text">Branches</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sidenav-button" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <mat-icon class="sidenav-button-icon">history</mat-icon>
    <span class="sidenav-button-text">Action Logs</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sidenav-button" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <mat-icon class="sidenav-button-icon">settings</mat-icon>
    <span class="sidenav-button-text">Profiles</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now, I'm using query params in the url to handle that case, but this is not optimal.

I have tried the following:

```
<div class="sidenav-button" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayoutAlign="start center" routerLinkActive="sidenav-button-active"
  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:
false}" [routerLink]="['/branches', selectedCompany]">
```

A company is being selected on the branch page itself, this html code is from the sidenav which navigates to the branch page. For the first navigation it works fine, but when a new company is being selected in the branch page, the class is not applies anymore.

Comment: Can  you please show what have you tried?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is syntax error. You should take this approach only by using `routerLinkActive`.

I have tried this in my project and its working.

```
<div class="sidenav-button" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayoutAlign="start center" 
    [routerLinkActive]="['sidenav-button-active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]={exact:false}"
    [routerLink]="['/branches', selectedCompany]">
```